# Использование нескольких операторов '?'

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте. Хочу переписать скрипт, используя конструкцию:

> условие ? выражение1 : выражение2

```
$('#search-btn').click(function () {
    console.log('test')
    if ( $(".boolean ").hasClass("checked")) {
        return
    }
    else if( $('#search_material').val() == ''){
        $('#search_material').focus()
    }
    else $('.type-checkbox ').addClass('active-confirm');    
});
```

У меня, к сожалению, не выходит сделать рабочий вариант. 
Подскажите, в чем ошибка?

```
   $('#search-btn').click(function () {

    ( $(".boolean ").hasClass("checked") ) ?  return :

   ( $('#search_material').val() == '') ?  $('#search_material').focus() :

    $('.type-checkbox ').addClass('active-confirm');

 });
```

Comment: `return :` - так можно? Нет, нельзя.

Comment: В тернарных операторах нельзя использовать другие операторы, в частности, <code>return</code>. Используйте его, чтобы возвращать **результат** условия.

Comment: Ошибка заключается в использовании не того инструмента. В данном случае не стоит переписывать условия с помощью тернарных операторов

Comment: из одного костыля другой собрались делать? Если у вас внутри `if` написан `return` то на кой черт вы пишите `else` вообще? просто продолжайте код дальше

Comment: тут лучше вообще без условий обойтись: `$(".boolean ").hasClass("checked") || $('#search_material').val() == '' && $('#search_material').focus() || $('.type-checkbox ').addClass('active-confirm')`

Comment: @Grundy да ну нахер :) такое ради забавы только писать, неподдерживаемый треш :) не учите такому :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо return поставьте пустое выражение '' 
всё равно у вас по логике функции после условия нет никаких действий.

Чтобы выполнялось каждое подвыражение - "условие ? выражение1 : выражение2" бери в круглые скобки,
например:

`((условие) ? выражение1 : выражение2)`

```
$('#search-btn').click(function () {

    ( $(".boolean ").hasClass("checked") ) ?  '' :

   (( $('#search_material').val() == '') ?  $('#search_material').focus() :

    $('.type-checkbox ').addClass('active-confirm'));

 });
```

Answer (score 2):

Упростим задачу:

```js
function aaa() {
  (true)? return : 2;
}
```

Смотрим ошибку в консоли.

Answer (score 0):

А если вот так?

```
$('#search-btn').click(function () {
    var $s = $('#search_material'),
        $c = $('.type-checkbox '),

        b = $(".boolean").hasClass("checked"),
        s = $s.val();

    b ? null : s ? $s.focus() : $c.addClass('active-confirm');      
});
```

Answer (score -1):

А так будет работать? Если второе условие полностью взять в скобки. У вас же сейчас поидее получается `a ? b : c ? d : e` а надо `a ? b : (c ? d : e)`

```
 $('#search-btn').click(function () {

    ( $(".boolean ").hasClass("checked") ) ?  return :

   (( $('#search_material').val() == '') ?  $('#search_material').focus() :

    $('.type-checkbox ').addClass('active-confirm'));

 });
```